# select the relationship on one to many in two table joined

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

```
a16s            
id  pic     
1   1.jpg       
2   2.jpg       
3   3.jpg       
4   4.jpg       

a16s_like           
id  p_id u_id   approve
1   1       2   0
2   1       1   1
3   1       5   1
4   1       6   1
5   1       7   0
6   2       2   0
7   2       3   0
8   2       1   1
9   4       4   0
10  4       3   1
11  4       2   1


$sql="SELECT A.id, A.pic

(select count(*) from a16s_like B where B.p_id = A.id) AS Ashow, 
(select count(*) from a16s_like B where B.p_id = A.id and B.approve='0') AS Nshow,
(select count(*) from a16s_like B where B.p_id = A.id and B.approve='1') AS Yshow
FROM a16s A  ORDER BY id DESC";
```

I use the approve colume three times, can any method to eloquent the seach?
My purposer is

when the u_id=2 to excute the select , I want to get

```
id pic    Ashowocunt  approve_0_count  approve_1_count     u_id2_approve   
1  1.jpg   5          2                3                   0
2  2.jpg   3          2                1                   0
3  3.jpg   0          0                0                   null
4. 4.jpg   3          0                3                   0
```

u_id=3

```
id pic    Ashowocunt  approve_0_count  approve_1_count     u_id3_approve   
1  1.jpg   0          0                0                   null
2  2.jpg   0          1                0                   0
3  3.jpg   0          0                0                   null
4. 4.jpg   1          0                1                   1
```

need to show all a.id  for the variable u_id,just like u_id=2 or u_id=3(have null)

Comment: I saw your expect result. I edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It'work so good! I  love this code!

Comment: You are welcome,sorry I misunderstand your question at first time I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

Use `CASE` express and `FULL OUTER JOIN`

But Mysql didn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN` , so you need to use `LEFT JOIN` and `Right JOIN` to make it.

```
SELECT 
    A.id, 
    A.PIC, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Ashowocunt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nshow,
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yshow
FROM  
(
  SELECT A.id ID
  FROM  a16s AS A
  LEFT JOIN a16s_like  AS B ON A.ID = B.p_id 
  UNION 
  SELECT B.p_id ID
  FROM  a16s AS A
  RIGHT JOIN a16s_like  AS B ON A.ID = B.p_id 
) AS T
LEFT JOIN a16s AS A ON A.ID = T.ID
LEFT JOIN a16s_like  AS B ON T.ID = B.p_id 
GROUP BY A.id,A.PIC
```

**EDIT**

You can use subquery on `a16s_like`

```
SELECT 
    A.id, 
    A.PIC, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Ashowocunt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nshow,
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yshow
FROM  
(
  SELECT A.id ID
  FROM  a16s AS A
  LEFT JOIN a16s_like  AS B ON A.ID = B.p_id 
  UNION 
  SELECT B.p_id ID
  FROM  a16s AS A
  RIGHT JOIN a16s_like  AS B ON A.ID = B.p_id 
) AS T
LEFT JOIN a16s AS A ON A.ID = T.ID
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT * 
FROM  a16s_like
WHERE u_id=2
)  AS B ON T.ID = B.p_id 
GROUP BY A.id,A.PIC
```

on another way  you can set `B.approve=1 AND B.u_id=2` on the `CASE` express

```
SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=1 AND B.u_id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yshow
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/979ad8/14)

Comment: thanks for your help. But can I get all A.id in a list as the approve colume may be null to some A.id. I refix my purpose more clearly. Is that list possible?

Comment: @robspin My new query can show all `a16s.id`,If result 
Not as your expection, Could you provide you expect result?

Comment: I  found the approve state is the first place of p_id. Can I send the u_id as variable to find the correct approve state of selected u_id, like u_id=2

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END where B.u_id=2) AS u_idapprove,   I can put the where in where? it just guess and it cannot work.

Comment: I edit my answer,Is it your expect?  you can create a subquery then put your condition in it.

Comment: I’m very grateful for your kind assistance. I use                                     
SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=1 AND B.u_id=2 THEN 1 when B.approve=0 AND B.u_id=2 then 0 ELSE null END) AS u_id2show  to get my purpose. Wish you a happy day~